# How to format only one offset but support mutiples offsets with DateTimeFormatterBuilder with a migration from joda?

Tags: java, jodatime, java-time, datetimeformatter

I want to migrate my code from Joda to java.time.
I use DateTimeFormatter for parsing and formating multiple date.
The problem is with DateTimeFormatter.format(...), the return String is "2023-02-08T09:30:00.000+01:00+0100+01" instead of 2023-02-08T09:30:00.000+01:00

I writed a test to expose my issue. The wrong test is testFormatWithJava()

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor;
import java.util.Date;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestU {

    private DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        DateTimeFormatterBuilder dateTimeFormatterBuilder = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME) //
                .optionalStart().appendPattern(".SSS").optionalEnd() //
                .optionalStart().appendOffset("+HH:MM", "+00:00").optionalEnd() //
                .optionalStart().appendOffset("+HHMM", "+0000").optionalEnd() //
                .optionalStart().appendOffset("+HH", "Z").optionalEnd();
        dateTimeFormatter = dateTimeFormatterBuilder.toFormatter();
    }

    @Test
    public void testParseDateStringWithJoda() {
        String dateString1 = "2023-02-08T09:30:00.787+0000";
        String dateString2 = "2023-02-08t09:30:00.000+01:00";
        String dateString3 = "2013-07-05t14:04:15+01:00";

        org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().withOffsetParsed();
        org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter formatterWithoutMs = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis()
                .withOffsetParsed();

        DateTime dateTime1 = formatter.parseDateTime(dateString1);
        DateTime dateTime2 = formatter.parseDateTime(dateString2);
        DateTime dateTime3 = formatterWithoutMs.parseDateTime(dateString3);

        assertEquals("Wed Feb 08 10:30:00 CET 2023", dateTime1.toDate().toString());
        assertEquals("Wed Feb 08 09:30:00 CET 2023", dateTime2.toDate().toString());
        assertEquals("Fri Jul 05 15:04:15 CEST 2013", dateTime3.toDate().toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void testParseDateStringWithJava() {
        String dateString1 = "2023-02-08T09:30:00.787+0000";
        String dateString2 = "2023-02-08t09:30:00.000+01:00";
        String dateString3 = "2013-07-05t14:04:15+01:00";

        TemporalAccessor temporalAccessor1 = dateTimeFormatter.parse(dateString1);
        TemporalAccessor temporalAccessor2 = dateTimeFormatter.parse(dateString2);
        TemporalAccessor temporalAccessor3 = dateTimeFormatter.parse(dateString3);

        assertEquals("Wed Feb 08 10:30:00 CET 2023", Date.from(Instant.from(temporalAccessor1)).toString());
        assertEquals("Wed Feb 08 09:30:00 CET 2023", Date.from(Instant.from(temporalAccessor2)).toString());
        assertEquals("Fri Jul 05 15:04:15 CEST 2013", Date.from(Instant.from(temporalAccessor3)).toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void testFormatWithJoda() {
        Date date = Date.from(LocalDateTime.of(2023, 02, 8, 9, 30).atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris")).toInstant());

        org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().withOffsetParsed();
        DateTime dt = new DateTime(date);

        assertEquals("2023-02-08T09:30:00.000+01:00", formatter.print(dt));
    }

    @Test
    public void testFormatWithJava() {
        Date date = Date.from(LocalDateTime.of(2023, 02, 8, 9, 30).atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris")).toInstant());

        assertEquals("2023-02-08T09:30:00.000+01:00",
                dateTimeFormatter.withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(date.toInstant()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you involving the old and poorly designed `Date` class too? Wondering very much.

Comment: I suggest separating formatting and parsing. You want that you can parse different variants, but when formatting you want one specific of those variants. So use one formatter for parsing (with optional parts) and another one for formatting (with no optional parts).

Comment: I must use old Date, because this a old projet and we don't use (Instant, LocalDate etc.). But thank you for your answer, I try to use a formater for "parsing" and "formating". It seems ok.

Answer (score 0):

You want to be able to parse 4 possible formats, not 4 concatenated optional ends.

You should use [DateTimeFormatterBuilder#appendOptional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendOptional-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-) to add the 4 variants you want to your DateTimeFormatterBuilder.

Something like this:

```
dateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
    .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("with .SSS"))
    .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("with +HH:MM"))
    .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("with +HHMM"))
    .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("with +HHZ"))
    .toFormatter();
```

Comment: I did that on before method isn't it ? or I don't understand your awnser

Comment: I've updated my answer to better explain what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Optional parts are good for parsing string to DateTime instance, but not for formatting. When formatting you should create 1 or several DateTimeFormatters without any optional parts that would reflect your standard how the date should be formatted. Optional parts are good for parsing strings where the strings may come in several formats and you don't have any control over it. I once wrote a feature where I tried to parse string in any known format. So I had a property file where I had several formats one after another that should cover all the possibilities and I tried to parse the incoming string with each format one after another until first success or until I ran out of formats. Having it in file allowed me to add and rearange formats without changing the code. I wrote an article about it where I described in detail the idea. Here is the article: [Java 8 java.time package: parsing any string to date](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/java-8-javatime-package-parsing-any-string-date-michael-gantman/)